# Detect if the browser blocking pop ups

Tags: javascript, jquery

In Jquery/Javascript Is there a way to detect if the browser (chrome in my case) is blocking popups when my web loads?
If that is not possible, then an alert before my window.open command will be satisfying as well.

I know this question already been asked before, but the questions are pretty out dated and I can't find a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: It's safe to assume that modern browsers will disallow `window.open()` calls in any case other than an interactive event handler.

Comment: `w = window.open(...); if (w == null) { alert('open failed'); }`

Answer (score 1):

You could try to open an invisible popup which is updating the php session variable to "true" if it is opened and if not, leaves it to "false", for example:

Once the user opens your site: session_start() and set session variable "$_SESSION["popupEnabled"]" to FALSE. After the site has been sent to the users browser execute a JS script which loads an AJAX request to another PHP script with just 2 lines of code: session_start(); and "$_SESSION["popupEnabled"]" to TRUE.

Now you can check systemwide:

```
If($_SESSION["popupEnabled"] == FALSE)   
{
 echo 'popups NOT allowed';
}
else
{
 echo 'popups allowed';
}
```

Comment: can't see anywhere that he was using php

Comment: Can be done completely with js  ajax requests,  only the ajax requested Files have to contain php with this solution

Comment: I'm not using PHP, but I can use your advise. just one question, how do I open an invisible page with window.open?

Comment: Size it 1x1px and close it directly after loading the document. In some cases you will See something But mostly it will be invisible